# Webshop matrixrate not working on multiple stores in magento2

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping-methods

We have installed webshop matrixrate extension for our magento2 store.

Its not working in checkout, Getting below error

```
Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time
```

Even we have records in table. Matrix rate is enabled in backend.

I have enabled the module in Main website, Please anyone suggest on this. Thanks

Comment: Can you share your csv what you have used?

Comment: @SukumarGorai, I have fixed it, problem with shopping cart rules.
It will be helpful if you update your answer here, https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/251362/hide-state-province-from-estimate-and-shipping-tax-from-cart-page-magento2

Comment: Please share you Table rate CSV So i can check and which magento 2 version you are using?

Comment: @PurushotamSharma, It is resolved now and i written the answer, if you can please help with this issue, https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/251362/hide-state-province-from-estimate-and-shipping-tax-from-cart-page-magento2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Problem was in shopping cart rules.

Defined one rule with free shipping. That was causing the problem.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/313671/57334 any help thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try `php bin/magento indexer:reindex` and change permissions to 755 you'll get solution.

Comment: hi @Ramesh KR, change permissions to 755 to full folder? reindex i did, but that didn't solve for me

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/313671/57334 any help thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try php bin/magento indexer:reindex

If not solved then check webshop Matrixrate Shipping Method Configuration Settings on store level (I think method is not enable on store level)

Comment: I have resolved this issue, I have posted my answer. Thanks