# Hide State/Province from Estimate and shipping tax from cart page magento2

Tags: magento2, cart, shopping-cart

How to remove State/Province field from the cart page?

I tried using jquery to remove it, that didn't work for me.

```
<script>
  require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){ 

    $(document).ready(function($){
        var checkList = setInterval(function() {
            if($("#shipping-zip-form").length > 0 ){    

                    //$("input[name='shippingAddress.region']").hide();                                     
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        $("input[name='shippingAddress.region']").hide();
                    }, 2000);                               
                    clearInterval(checkList);
                  }
            }, 2000); // check every 1000ms

      });  
  });
 </script>
```

Is there anyway available to remove it from xml or php code? Please anybody help on this thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it by following method:
Create a file with name **checkout_cart_index.xml** under

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml

and add the below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.shipping">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="block-summary" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="block-shipping" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="address-fieldsets" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="region_id" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                                <item name="region" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Thats it! Need to flush the cache and test.

Comment: hi @Sukumar, It works!! great.

Comment: Welcome. Happy Coding!

Comment: can you please help on this as well, https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/251640/setting-custom-product-attribute-value-in-magento-2

Comment: I ll check and let you know.

Comment: On v.2.3.1 this breaks the 'estimate shipping and tax' if a customer is signed into their account. It works for guest though

Answer (score 0):

what would I need to add to also hide the Country?

And also this removes it from my cart page but the fields still appear on the checkout page, is there a way to remove from checkout page too?