# How to Load JS Code at the Top Using RequireJS

Tags: magento2, requirejs, requirejs-config.js

How can I load a custom JavaScript file using RequireJS at the very beginning? Please note: The key is that RequireJS must load my script FIRST, before any other scripts, as the rest of my script depends on that file.

Currently, my:

> requirejs-config.js

Has the following code:

```
var config = {
    deps: [
        'js/myJS',
    ]
};
```

My file, located in app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/web/myJS.js, is working, but it's being loaded AFTER the rest of the RequireJS files. How can I load myJS.js to be the very first file RequireJS loads?

Comment: so is the rest of your script in another js file?

Comment: I need to load it before all of Magento's stock JS files too. It needs to be the very first JS code loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case it's probably easier to overwrite `root.phtml` instead of using `require.js`.

Copy default `root.phtml` from `vendor/magento/module-theme/view/base/templates/` to your theme location `app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Theme/templates/`. Edit the file to include your script right before or after where `require.js` is included. It'll look something like this,

```
<!doctype html>
<html <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $htmlAttributes ?>>
    <head <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $headAttributes ?>>        
        <script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/your/custom.js"></script>
        <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $requireJs ?>
        <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $headContent ?>
        <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $headAdditional ?>
    </head>
    <body data-container="body" data-mage-init='{"loaderAjax": {}, "loader": { "icon": "<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $loaderIcon ?>"}}' <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $bodyAttributes ?>>
        <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $layoutContent ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: hi @subroutines, can you check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/251362/hide-state-province-from-estimate-and-shipping-tax-from-cart-page-magento2

Comment: This is what I wanted, thank you! But how do I get the base URL so I can link to my file? I tried <?php echo $this->getBaseUrl(); ?> but it doesn't work. Linking directly yields a 404 error.

Comment: I got it! I was able to insert my script at the top by overriding root.phtml as you suggested then, right after <head>, putting: <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl( '/' ); ?>/js/myJS.js"></script>